# Passing slashed argument to requestAction in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to pass a string to requestaction.

in **myController** file:

```
public function myAction($name) {
    $data = unserialize( file_get_contents( $name) );
    return $data;
}
```

in my Views file:

```
$f="/home/myaccount/file.txt";

$g = $this->requestAction( array( 'controller' => 'myController',
         'action' => 'myAction' ), $f );
```

How can I pass an argument having special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the following code will help you:

```
 $g = $this->requestAction('/myController/myAction', array('pass' => urlencode($f));
```

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) will guide you how to access the parameter in your controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is:

```
$g = $this->requestAction('app/myController/'.urlencode($f));
```